# Relational Algebra instead of SQL

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I am studying relational algebra these days and I was wondering...

Don't you thing it would be better if a compiler was existed which could compile relational algebra than compiling SQL?

In which case a database programmer would be more productive?

Is there any research on relational algebra compilers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

See [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(data_language_specification)) by C J Date, he also has a good rant somewhere on the evils of SQL.

Also see [datalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog), although not exactly relational algebra, is similar.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what is going on.  There appears to be a //tp being inserted.  Look up Tutorial D on wikipedia.  There is also an implementation of Tutorial D called rel.  C J Date's rant is entitled "A critique of the SQL database language", but it is behind a paywall.  If you are a student you should be able to get it.

Comment: I am not a student, I was refreshing relational algebra, I have written maany lines of SQL but reconsidered relational algebra as better than SQL.

Comment: Datalog is exactly relational algebra plus transitive closure.

Answer (score 3):

On my school one student implemented relational algebra parser as a Bachelor thesis. You can test it here:
http://mufin.fi.muni.cz/projects/PA152/relalg/index.cgi

It's in czech language but I think you can get a point.

I tried to write some Relational Algebra queries and it was much better than equivalent queries in SQL! They were much shorter, simplier to write, more straightforward, more understandable. I really enjoyed to write them.

So I don't understand why we all are using SQL when there is Relational Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed research on compiling relational algebra

A good place to start:
Thomas Neumann: Efficiently Compiling Efficient Query Plans for Modern Hardware. PVLDB 4(9): 539-550 (2011)